# constants in Pytorch Linear Module Class Definition

Tags: pytorch

What is `__constants__` in pytorch `class Linear(Module):` defined in https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/linear.html?

What is its functionality and why is it used?

I have been searching around, but did not find any documentation. Please note that this does not mean the `__constants__` in torch script.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `__constants__` you're talking about is, in fact, the one related to TorchScript. You can confirm it by using `git blame` *(when it was added and by who)* on GitHub. For example, for [`torch/nn/modules/linear.py`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/linear.py), check its [git blame](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blame/master/torch/nn/modules/linear.py).

> [TorchScript](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/jit.html#python-defined-constants) also provides a way to use constants that are defined in Python. These can be used to hard-code hyper-parameters into the function, or to define universal constants.
>
> -- Attributes of a ScriptModule can be marked constant by listing them as a member of the **constants** property of the class:

```py
class Foo(torch.jit.ScriptModule):
    __constants__ = ['a']

    def __init__(self):
        super(Foo, self).__init__(False)
        self.a = 1 + 4

   @torch.jit.script_method
   def forward(self, input):
       return self.a + input
```